# Find Word in RegEx while ignoring special characters

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to find the word "string" in the following string and ignore any special characters in between.
e.g.,

String s = "this is a sample string. In this st@ring I would like to search my s%#tring";

the result should be "3 matches": 
string
s@tring
s%#tring

It should simply ignore these characters @ % #

Answer (score 1):

you may use this:

```
s[^string]*?t[^string]*?r[^string]*?i[^string]*?n[^string]*?g
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/xP5iT1/1

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
\bs[^A-Za-z0-9\s]*?t[^A-Za-z0-9\s]*?r[^A-Za-z0-9\s]*?i[^A-Za-z0-9\s]*?n[^A-Za-z0-9\s]*?g\b
```

`[^A-Za-z0-9\s]` Matches any character but not of alphanumeric or space character.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL2lG2/1)

Java code would be,

```
String s = "this is a sample string. In this st@ring I would like to search my s%#tring";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\bs[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]*?t[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]*?r[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]*?i[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]*?n[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]*g\\b");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
string
st@ring
s%#tring
```